# Find closest path to number in a cycling order

Tags: math, pseudocode

I'm trying to find the closest path to a number which can go in a cycling order, for example:

- I have the numbers 0 to 4 which could go in both directions(after 4 comes 0, before 0 comes 4).
- If I'm currently at 1 and I want to go to 2, the closest path would be going forward.
- If I'm currently at 3 and I want to go to 0, the closest path would be going forward.
- If I'm currently at 2 and I want to go to 1, the closest path would be going backwards.

That was probably clear enough after the first 1 or 2 examples.

I'd like to implement something similar in code, I can easily do that with a couple of if's etc, but I'm pretty sure there must be a better easier way to determine the closest path using math, not really sure how to though, if someone could help with approaching this that would be very useful,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using modular arithmetic, you could define one function to compute forward distances, another function to compute backwards distances, and a third to decide between the two. Here is a python solution which should be easily translatable to other languages (though different languages handle how negative numbers are treated by the mod operator, so some care might be required):

```
def forward(i,j,n):
    return (j-i) % n

def backwards(i,j,n):
    return (i-j) % n

def best_direction(i,j,n):
    f = forward(i,j,n)
    b = backwards(i,j,n)
    if f < b:
        return 'forward'
    elif b < f:
        return 'backwards'
    else:
        return 'either'
```

Your test cases (run in a Python shell):

```
>>> best_direction(1,2,5)
'forward'
>>> best_direction(3,0,5)
'forward'
>>> best_direction(2,1,5)
'backwards'
```

Another test case, showing the possibility of a tie:

```
>>> best_direction(3,0,6)
'either'
```

Obviously, you can inline the two 1-line functions into the definition of `best_direction` to get it down to a single function definition if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, accepted it as the accepted answer. One thing that did got me confused is the use of python modulo is pseudo code, as it seems like it behaves differently than most(or all, idk) languages, so when I tried implementing that I was struggling to understand why it didn't work, ended up figuring I need to make a custom mod to make it similar to the way python does it. thanks!!

Comment: @uhuvkvhartk There is a [surprising diversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in how modulo is implemented. Python's is reasonably common (especially with newer languages) and coincides with how a mathematician would expect `a % n` to work with negative `a` and positive `n`.

Comment: Yep read about all that, I was just a bit confused at first as I didn't knew about that, very interesting, thanks :)